# how to draw shape in the svg like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am new to the SVG,

**I have a SVG Path like this**

**SVG Path is**

```
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             width="841.891px" height="595.279px" viewBox="0 0 841.891 595.279" enable-background="new 0 0 841.891 595.279"
             xml:space="preserve">

<g id="_x32_d">
        <path fill="#009444" d="M225.029,226.478v39.131h39.131v-39.131H225.029L225.029,226.478z M259.087,260.536h-28.984v-28.985h28.984
        V260.536z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

[image]

[image]

**Upon clicking the button, how can i generate polygon line**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need only a polygon line or the shape that you have shown as well?

Comment: i need the shape same i given... This is my clear req (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415567/how-to-generate-3d-view-in-the-svg).. the polygon shape should start end of the corner

Comment: @tumulr if we cant achieve the shape, let us try from the polygon line & we can try to bring the shape

Comment: The shape that you want to achieve is not possible with svg polyline.

Comment: ok is there any alternative way to achieve ? if yes, can give me with sample example...

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as Inkscape and use it to draw the shape you want.